# Omit Certain Entries from Apache Access Log

Tags: apache-httpd

Is there a simple way to keep noise entries out of the `access_log` file short of doing piped logging to a script that does a `grep -v` on matching criteria or something?

I have `collectd` monitoring apache statistics but as a consequence I get these messages:

```
157.98.65.xxx - - [23/Apr/2014:09:46:32 -0400] "GET /server-status/?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 439 "-" "collectd/4.10.9"
157.98.65.xxx - - [23/Apr/2014:09:46:32 -0400] "GET /server-status/?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 439 "-" "collectd/4.10.9"
```

When they run analytics against the apache logs they now get an entry for this which isn't really related to why they're wanting to run the analytics (they don't care about activity due to sysadmin monitoring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `SetEnvIf` and the `env=` in the log definition.

The Apache manual covers it under 'conditional logging', quoting here.

> *Conditional Logs*
>
> There are times when it is convenient to exclude certain entries from
>   the access logs based on characteristics of the client request. This
>   is easily accomplished with the help of environment variables. First,
>   an environment variable must be set to indicate that the request meets
>   certain conditions. This is usually accomplished with `SetEnvIf`. Then
>   the `env=` clause of the `CustomLog` directive is used to include or
>   exclude requests where the environment variable is set. Some examples:

```
# Mark requests from the loop-back interface 
  SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
# Mark requests for the robots.txt file 
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" dontlog
# Log what remains 
  CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

It's covered in [this section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html) of the manual.

You would be looking for something like (not tested)

`SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "157\.98\.65\.xxx" dontlog`

or

`SetEnvIf User-Agent "collectd/4\.10\.9" dontlog`

Comment: I verified with a phpinfo() that `dontlog` is getting set to "1" by my `SetEnvIf` but I'm still seeing the requests in `access_log` even after doing `CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!dontlog` Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: After looking into it further, it looks like there's a second `CustomLog` directive in a `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf` file but they didn't uncomment the one in the main file. It's already filtering based on `SentEnfIf` filtering for different criteria. Is there a way to combine the two so that they're both required? I was thinking of chaining multiple `SetEnvIf` directives together but I wasn't sure how to make it work.

Comment: For posterity [I found this](http://stephane.lesimple.fr/blog/2010-01-28/apache-logical-or-and-conditions-with-setenvif.html) which explains how to approximate "OR"/"AND" for conditionals.

Comment: I found that same document but ran out of time and had to leave the answer as it was while travelling.  Glad you got it working.